# use value from input datepicker

Tags: javascript, c#, datepicker

I have a problem, I want to compare the value from the datepicker ins aspx. with the value in a ms sql table column. I already created the input datepicker and the function in javascript, but I don't know how to use in c# code-behind the value that I chose! Can someone please help me?

```
$(function () {

        $("#anfang").datepicker({
            prevText: '&#x3c;zurück', prevStatus: '',
            prevJumpText: '&#x3c;&#x3c;', prevJumpStatus: '',
            nextText: 'Vor&#x3e;', nextStatus: '',
            nextJumpText: '&#x3e;&#x3e;', nextJumpStatus: '',
            currentText: 'heute', currentStatus: '',
            todayText: 'heute', todayStatus: '',
            clearText: '-', clearStatus: '',
            closeText: 'schließen', closeStatus: '',
            monthNames: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni',
            'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mär', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
            dayNames: ['Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So'],
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            showOn: 'both',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            defaultDate: "+0w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#Label1").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $("#ende").datepicker({
            prevText: '&#x3c;zurück', prevStatus: '',
            prevJumpText: '&#x3c;&#x3c;', prevJumpStatus: '',
            nextText: 'Vor&#x3e;', nextStatus: '',
            nextJumpText: '&#x3e;&#x3e;', nextJumpStatus: '',
            currentText: 'heute', currentStatus: '',
            todayText: 'heute', todayStatus: '',
            clearText: '-', clearStatus: '',
            closeText: 'schließen', closeStatus: '',
            monthNames: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni',
            'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mär', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
            dayNames: ['Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So'],
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            beforeShow: customRange,
            showOn: 'both',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            defaultDate: "+0w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#Label2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
    })
```

and:

```
<asp:Label ID="von" runat="server" Text="Von: "></asp:Label>
    <input type="text" id="anfang" />
    <asp:Label ID="bis" runat="server" Text="Bis: "></asp:Label>
    <input type="text" id="ende" />
```

Comment: What do you mean compare? The only way to do that is to send it back to the server using either AJAX call (GET or POST) or with a form POST. If its something like making sure that start date is smaller then end date you should do that client side using something like JQUERY and then again during the actual form post on the server.

Comment: @Igor I mean, I have to create a line-chart with the date that i chose from a datepicker. the sql table is really long, so I have to search the date inside, thats why i have to get the value from datepicker in c# where I use the sql request.

Comment: Ok. So it sounds like you are not sure how to access the value of the pickers in your code behind during the postback of the form. In that case @fubo has the correct answer. Adding `runat="server"` to any element allows you to access that element in the code behind by `id`.

Comment: @Igor ah ok, thank you, i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
<input type="text" id="anfang" />
```

with

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="anfang" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

to make your input elements `anfang` and `ende` serverside and access them codebehind with

```
string result = anfang.Text;
```

Comment: Can I use a textbox as a datepicker?

Comment: sure, a `TextBox` is rendered as `input` - imo it's more consistent not to mix up html and asp controls

Comment: datepicker really works with textbox, I always read many webs which all are using input, thank you very much!!